# How to train an object detection model with variable output size?

Tags: image, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

Assume we are working on the following dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/jutrera/stanford-car-dataset-by-classes-folder.

I want to create object detection model with input as images of different shapes and output also as images of variable shapes but the output images are cropped cars from the corresponding input images(hence the variable shapes). How to achieve this using Keras. I know the process of image segmentation and auto-encoders but as the size of input and outputs are variable, the exact process seems distant. Pls help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Tensorflow Object Detection API and use the output bounding boxes to crop your input images. Note that the input images will be resized, but you can use the output bounding boxes to crop the original image.

```
detections = detect(input_tensor)

bounding_boxes = detections['detection_boxes'].numpy()
confidences = detections['detection_scores'].numpy()

for bbox, conf, path in zip(bounding_boxes, confidences, image_path):
    if len(bbox):
        image_orig = load_orig(path) # load original size image
        height, width, channels = image_orig.shape
        y_min, x_min, y_max, x_max = bbox
        y_min_absolute = int(y_min * height)
        x_min_absolute = int(x_min * width)
        y_max_absolute = int(y_max * height)
        x_max_absolute = int(x_max * width)

        cropped_image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(
            image=image_orig,
            offset_height=y_min_absolute,
            offset_width=x_min_absolute,
            target_height=y_max_absolute - y_min_absolute,
            target_width=x_max_absolute - x_min_absolute)

        cropped_images.append(tf.cast(cropped_image, tf.uint8))
```